# How to return a List of objects from an async task

Tags: .net, async-await

I'm trying to implement .NET 4.5 async/await and am running into a few issues.

I have this code:

```
private async void GetPages()
{
    PageList = await _dataService.GetPageList(JobTypeId);
}
```

IDataService looks like this

```
public interface IDataService
{
    Task<List<PageDto>> GetPageList(int jobTypeId);
}
```

and DataService.GetPageList like this:

```
public Task<List<PageDto>> GetPageList(int jobTypeId)
{
    var retval = new List<PageDto>();

    try
    {
        retval =
            (from p in _connection.Table<PageDto>()
                where p.JobTypeId == jobTypeId
                select p).ToList();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Exception(ex);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

I somehow need to wrap the result in a task but I can't figure out how.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I can't use ToListAsync due to limitations in the SQLLite library I'm using but how about something like this?

```
public async Task<List<PageDto>> GetPageListAsync(int jobTypeId)
{
    var retval = new List<PageDto>();

    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            retval =
                (from jtp in _connection.Table<JobTypePage>()
                 join p in _connection.Table<PageDto>() on jtp.PageId equals p.PageId
                 where jtp.JobTypeId == jobTypeId
                 orderby jtp.JobTypePageId
                 select p).ToList();
        });

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Exception(ex);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should be using asynchronous methods from the inside-out (not "imposing" async from the outside-in). In this case, I assume you're using EF6, so you could do:

```
retval = await
    (from p in _connection.Table<PageDto>()
        where p.JobTypeId == jobTypeId
        select p).ToListAsync();
```

And then you can just mark your method `async`:

```
public async Task<List<PageDto>> GetPageListAsync(int jobTypeId)
```

As I side note, I added the `Async` suffix to follow the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

For more information, check out my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Stephen, Any reason for not returning task returned from `ToListAsync` and awaiting it?

Comment: It changes the error handling in this example. The error handling strategy the op is using is not one I would choose myself, but if the rest of the code assumes errors are logged and then ignored by the data service, then it's important for consistency.

Comment: It's SQLLite which does not have a ToListAsync method. I'm attempting to upgrade an old app that used backgroundworker.

Comment: If I can't use async from the inside out - due to the SQlLite library I'm using not supporting async - how would I then impose async from the outside in? Or is there another way?

Comment: Stephen - I added a possible solution to my question. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Newer versions of SQLite (at least SQLite.NET) do support `async`. So check for a new version first, but if it still doesn't support it, then the proper solution is to return a plain `List<T>` from `IDataService.GetPageList` and not use `async` at all there. Then use `Task.Run` when you *call* it from your UI layer: `PageList = await Task.Run(() => _dataService.GetPageList(JobTypeId));`

Comment: Thanks Stephen Can I also ask please what error handling strategy you would use?

Comment: I would always let the exceptions propagate to the next layer instead of returning an empty list.